# Get current stack size in FORTH

Tags: stack, forth

How can I get the number of elements currently held in the stack in Forth?

I ask this because I want to make a function that prints out all the elements of the stack, something like:

```
: pop_all 0 do . loop ;
1 5 10 4 5
5 pop_all
```

But now I need to manually specify the stack size when I call it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always find the number of items on the stack with the function
[`DEPTH`](http://forth-standard.org/standard/core/DEPTH). The value returned is the number of items on the stack before
the number is returned.

Comment: This link points to a different website now. Is an up-to-date link available?

Comment: @Anderson Green: You are right, the link is not available now. Unfortunately I've not found updated link :(

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for the return stack?

Answer (score 1):

Most FORTH systems have a `.S` command that does exactly what you want to write.

Comment: the word `.s` shows the stack content, while the word `depth` puts the stack length onto  the top of the stack.